# Javascript Concat Values of Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays like this:

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const b = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

I'm trying to make a new array like this:

```
const c = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4'];
```

I tried it this way:

```
const c = [];
c.push([`${a[0]}${b[0]}`, `${a[1]}${b[1]}`, `${a[2]}${b[2]}`, `${a[3]}${b[3]}`]);
```

With actually looping through data and doing this took 17400ms.

I took out the `c.push([........]);` and it dropped to 1250ms.

Why does this take so long to do?

And what is the best way to do this?

Comment: 17400ms for 4 elements?

Comment: It looks through an `Object.keys(obj).map()` and the obj has ~20k keys.

Comment: It seems you are doing lots of `push`, I would preallocate instead. And I would avoid template strings, here they are not useful at all and it wouldn't surprise me that they are less optimized because are so recent and used less frequently.

Comment: So you are not using template strings as one sane person won't use that syntax for 20k elements!

Comment: So, I played around with it and found out the Array.push() is the problem for taking so long.
@Oriol What do you mean by preallocate? I tried google but couldn't find what it was.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `.map` to achieve that. map `a`, then use index on each loop to get element of `b`.

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const b = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

var c = a.map(function (d, i) {
    return d + String(b[i])
})

console.log(c)
// ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4"]
```

cleaner code using es6:

```
var c = a.map((d, i) => `${d}${b[i]}`)
```

Comment: If they are integer?

Comment: No need to use `String`. The values of `b` are already strings, and if they were numbers they would be coerced to strings when concatenated with the strings from `a`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but the problem was with the Array.push(). I don't know what to do about that... Could you help?

Comment: this solution do not need to use Array.push(). I'm not quite understand about what you asking. can you explain ?

Comment: I need a big outer array holding these smaller arrays of 4 elements. So when I push these smaller arrays in a loop, it takes too long. Hopefully I made sense..

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const b = ['1', '2', '3'];
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected and you confirmed, the real problem is that you do too many `push`.

`push` modifies the length of the array. The specification does not enforce any data structure for arrays, but for non-sparse ones, implementations usually use lists which store the values consecutively in memory. That's problematic when you change the length of the array, because the additional data could not fit in the place in memory where the data currently is, so all data must be moved. `push` ends up being constant in amortized time instead of just constant.

However, if you know the length of the resulting array beforehand, it's usually better to preallocate.

Then, instead of

```
var array = [];
for(var i=0; i<2e4; ++i)
  array.push([a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2], a[3]+b[3]]);
```

I would use

```
var array = new Array(2e4);
for(var i=0; i<2e4; ++i)
  array[i] = [a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1], a[2]+b[2], a[3]+b[3]];
```

Comment: Interesting.. I never knew you could preallocate memory like that. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: What represent 2e4?